# nylon watch strap material; how to model and node setup

Tags: modeling, node-editor

im a beginner level at modelling in blender and have been working on making a wrist watch. This wristwatch in particular needs to have a nylon strap (or any similar fabric). I would really appreciate it if someone could perhaps help me out. I have attached two pictures with different nylon threading, whichever is easier to model.

Thank you for your time :) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0THM.jpg)[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. This is a site for *specific* questions with *specific* answers. Where, *specifically*, are you having trouble? What have you got so far?

Comment: What you are asking for requires a very in depth and timely explanation. There are many ways you could make what your asking but it would be beyond thew practicality of StackExchange to answer that unless you can narrow your question down to a single specific step/issue you need help with. I suggest watching some videos on you tube about modelling and texturing models. Andrew Price or Blender Cookie is a decent place to start if your a beginner.

Comment: @Ray is right, please be more precise. However, if you're after the threading, a simple *Normal map* might be a good solution.